# Piecewise defined funcion is Riemann-integrable

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ be the function given by $$f(x):=\begin{cases}0&\text{if}\;\;x\notin\mathbb Q\\q^{-1}&\text{if}\;\;x\in\mathbb Q,\;x=\frac{p}{q},\;p,q\in\mathbb N\;\text{and}\;\gcd(p,q)=1\end{cases}.$$ Then $f$ is continuous at irrational numbers, discontinuous at rational numbers and $f$ is Riemann-integrable on $[0,1].$

I've already proved everything here, but my proof of the fact that $f$ is integrable is, in my opinion, too long and I guess there is a short proof. I am familiar with the fact that if a function is bounded and its set of points of discontinuity is countable, then the function is integrable, however, I would like to see proofs that do not use this fact (nor "advanced" terms like "measure"). I leave my proof below.

$(i).$ To prove that $f$ is continuous at irrational numbers, I pick an arbitrary irrational $0<x<1,$ an arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$ and any integer $q>0$ such that $q^{-1}\leqslant\varepsilon.$ Then, for any positive integer $n$ we have $\lfloor nx\rfloor/n<x<(\lfloor nx\rfloor+1)/n$ because $x$ is not rational. Next, I define $\delta_n:=\min\{x-\lfloor nx\rfloor/n,-x+(\lfloor nx\rfloor+1)/n\}$ for each $n>0$ and finally $\lambda_x:=\min\{\delta_n,x,1-x\}_{n<q}.$ Then if $a/b$ is a reduced fraction (i.e. in lowest terms) such that $|x-a/b|<\lambda_x,$ one can easily prove that $0\leqslant a/b\leqslant1$ and that, if $b<q$ then $\lfloor bx\rfloor<a<\lfloor bx\rfloor+1,$ which implies that $b\geqslant q.$ The continuity of $f$ at $x$ then easily follows.

$(ii).$ To prove that $f$ is dicontinuous at rational numbers I just use the fact that $\mathbb R-\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R.$

$(iii).$ To prove that $f$ is integrable, first pick some $\varepsilon>0$ and some integer $q$ large enough so that $q^{-1}\leqslant\varepsilon.$ Next, I define $A$ to be the set of all reduced fractions $a/b$ in the unit interval, such that $b<q;$ this set is finite because there are exactly $\sum_{k=1}^{q-1}\phi(k)$ such fractions, where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function. Then I choose a partition $P=\{p_1,\ldots,p_n\}$ of the unit interval in such a way that each set $[p_{i-1},p_i]\cap A$ is either empty or consists of exactly one point and $\Delta p_i\leqslant(q+1)^{-m}$ if $[p_{i-1},p_i]$ contains a reduced fraction with denominator $m.$ Then, if $M_i:=\sup\{f(t)\}_{p_{i-1}\leqslant t\leqslant p_i},$ the upper sum $U=U(P,f)$ satisfies $$\begin{aligned}U&=\sum_{\substack{2\leqslant i\leqslant n\\A\cap[p_{i-1},p_i]=\varnothing}}M_i\Delta p_i+\sum_{\substack{2\leqslant i\leqslant n\\A\cap[p_{i-1},p_i]\neq\varnothing}}M_i\Delta p_i\\\\&\leqslant q^{-1}\sum_{\substack{2\leqslant i\leqslant n\\A\cap[p_{i-1},p_i]=\varnothing}}\Delta p_i+\sum_{\substack{2\leqslant i\leqslant n\\A\cap[p_{i-1},p_i]\neq\varnothing}}M_i\Delta p_i\\\\&\leqslant\varepsilon+\sum_{\substack{2\leqslant i\leqslant n\\A\cap[p_{i-1},p_i]\neq\varnothing}}M_i\Delta p_i,\end{aligned}$$
where $\Delta p_i:=p_i-p_{i-1}.$ Now, since, for each integer $1\leqslant m<q,$ there are exactly $\phi(m)$ many intervals $[p_{i-1},p_i]$ containing a reduced fraction with denominator $m$ and since for each of those intervals, $M_i=1/m,$ then $$\sum_{\substack{2\leqslant i\leqslant n\\A\cap[p_{i-1},p_i]\neq\varnothing}}M_i\Delta p_i\leqslant\sum_{m=1}^{q-1}\dfrac{\phi(m)}{m}(q+1)^{-m}\leqslant\sum_{m=1}^{q-1}(q+1)^{-m}=\dfrac{1}{q}\left[1-\dfrac{1}{(q+1)^{q-1}}\right]$$ and since $q^{-1}\leqslant\varepsilon$ then $U<2\varepsilon.$ This together with the fact that the lower sum $L(P,f)$ is zero (because of the density of $\mathbb R-\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$), implies that $\int_0^1f(x)dx=0.$